# Edit Order Functionality - WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, tax

Thank you for your time!

The below code does the following:

If a customer want to edit there order:

- A credit for the full amount previously paid is applied
- Customer can add/subtract items from there cart
- System calculates the new subtotal
- System calculates cart items tax
- Subtracts the new total from the customer credit to get the final new total

**The issue:**

When the system is calculating the Tax it add the Subtotal + Credit * Tax Rate.

For Example:

Order Details:

Subtotal $100.00

**Tax $4.48 (Subtotal - Credit * 8.8750%)**

Credit -$49.61

Total   $54.87

---

**When its supposed to be:**

Order Details:

Subtotal $100.00

**Tax $8.88 (Subtotal * 8.8750%)**

Credit -$49.61

Total   $59.27

---

I tried adding a third argument:
$cart->add_fee( 'Credit', $credit, false);

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

---

The code:

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'bbloomer_use_edit_order_total', 20, 1 );
   
function bbloomer_use_edit_order_total( $cart ) {
    
  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
     
  $edited = WC()->session->get('edit_order');
  if ( ! empty( $edited ) ) {
      $order = new WC_Order( $edited );
      $credit = -1 * $order->get_total();
      $cart->add_fee( 'Credit', $credit);
  }    
}
```